# Changing the cursor in an NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, macos, cursor, nstextview

I'm hoping this will be a relatively easy thing to do.

I am writing a Mac app that will be (mostly) a giant NSTextView. I would like to override the default text position cursor to a unique color/shape cursor. I don't have a lot of Quartz or general drawing experience but that's something I can look into more on my own.

What I'm primarily looking for is advice on the best way to implement this. Is it going to be a matter of overriding the drawRect function, calling the super, and then implementing my own draw code?

How would I find the appropriate location to draw that cursor? Is it contained within the drawRect's passed rect?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you'll have to subclass the NSTextView and override some methods. The obvious one is

```
-(void)drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)aRect color:(NSColor *)aColor turnedOn:(BOOL)flag
```

but that doesn't seem to entirely take care of it. Apparently, you also have to override a private method:

```
-(void)_drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)arg1 color:(NSColor *)color
```

Look here for someone who's already trying to do this:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CustomInsertionPoint

Comment: Sweet. Was hoping I wouldn't have to subclass to get it to work. Thanks for the tip. Going to leave this open for now just to see if a better response comes along. I'll select an answer(s) tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620)

Comment: Overriding a private method going to result in being declined on the App Store? If so, that needs to be taken into consideration on the answer.

Comment: It's possible they could bounce you over doing that. If you need to get in the App Store, then you might not be able to make a custom insertion point.

Comment: Applications like WriteRoom and iA Writer appear to do it and are in the app store. I'm curious if there's a better way to do it than described above.